# Pure parallax effect not working space on the left side

Tags: html, css, parallax

I have a strange problem with the pure css parallax effect. I followed this tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/tour-performant-responsive-css-site/

But like in the example i have a white space on the left hand site. After some research I have read that's should be a bug exclusive in webkit based browser but I get the same result in firefox too.

On this site: http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/ the author describe a work around:

> It is possible to work around for this bug by anchoring the transform-origin and perspective-origin to the right hand side of the viewport:

```
.parallax {
  perspective-origin-x: 100%;
}
.parallax__layer {
  transform-origin-x: 100%;
}
```

but that didn't do the trick.

I collect this in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s028mLkc/7/)

Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `#container`'s left from 0 to -7px. `left: -7px;`

Comment: thank's that's works like a charm. not really what i expected but it works. if you add this comment as an answer, then I can accept it as the correct answer

Comment: Admit it. added ;)

Comment: The accepted answer only appears to work at a glance. Resizing the page after applying dNitro's fix creates a gap on the right side of the page at larger browser sizes. Raoul's solution was the correct answer and makes sure there are no gaps on both sides, at any browser size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fine tuning the `#container`'s `left` property will do the trick:

```
left: -7px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace width: 100%; by width: 100vw; in the .background